# prove there is a unique set $X$ such that every set $Y$, $Y∪X = Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

For this proof. It seems obvious that $X=∅$ such that for every set $Y$,  $Y∪X = Y$ since the $Y∪X$ is just Y. How should I go about this?

Let there be sets $X,Z$

Since $Y∪X = Y$ then,

{$x| x ∈ Y ∨ x ∈ X$} = {$x| x ∈ Y$}

Since $Y∪Z = Y$ then,

{$x| x ∈ Y ∨ x ∈ Z$} = {$x| x ∈ Y$}

Then equate the two

{$x| x ∈ Y ∨ x ∈ Z$} = 
{$x| x ∈ Y ∨ x ∈ X$}

Therefore conlude Z = X and prove that X is a unique set.

Comment: Take $Y=\{a,b\}, X\{a\}, Z=\{b\}$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, the statement should hold for every set $Y$. Not just some $Y$

Comment: @Rise Oh, true. I rushed through the post :-p.

Comment: I need to prove uniqueness of X for every arbitrary set of Y though, I dont think I can just use examples. Z is just a set I made up in order to help me prove uniqueness. Like take x1 and x2 as sets and if x1 = x2 then conclude that it is unique

Answer (score 2):

First, check that $X=\emptyset$ works. Now, suppose there is another possibility $X\neq\emptyset$ that satisfies the requirement. Then, take $Y=\emptyset$, and note that
$$
Y\cup X\neq Y
$$
because the RHS is empty whereas the LHS equals $X$ and therefore has at least 1 element.

Comment: But If $X=∅$ it satisfies for all sets of $Y$ that  $Y∪X=Y$. I dont have to consider $X ≠∅$. What I'm trying to do is to prove that $X$ is unique. How will proving it that it has 1 element help me.

Comment: @JeffBridges This is a proof by contradiction. You suppose $X$ is _not_ unique. Therefore there is some other set (not just the empty set) with the desired property. You then show that whatever set that is, it does _not_ have the property, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

As Kim Jong Un said, the first is show that $\emptyset$ satisies your requirements.

Now, let if $X$ has the property, then, taking $Y=\emptyset$, $X\subseteq \emptyset\cup X=\emptyset$. Thus $X\subseteq \emptyset$ and done.

Comment: I understand everything that your suggesting it, but how does this go to help me prove uniqueness? I'm not trying to prove $X⊆∅$. I'm trying to prove that X is a unique set (which is $∅$) but can't be any other set in order for  $ Y∪X=Y $ to be true.

Comment: If you prove that $X \subseteq \emptyset$ then you prove that $X = \emptyset$.

Comment: The only subset the empty set has is the empty set.  If anything is a subset of the empty set that thing must be the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more step after your last equation: If $\{x :x\in Y\lor x\in Z\}=Y=\{x:x\in Y\lor x\in X\}$ holds for every $Y$, then it holds when $Y=X$: $$X=\{x:x\in X\lor x\in X\}=\{x: x\in X\lor x\in Z\}.$$ And it holds when $Y=Z$: $$Z=\{x:x\in Z\lor x\in Z\}=\{x:x\in Z\lor x\in X\}.$$ Comparing the RHS of these, we have $X=Z.$........ More succintly we can obtain $$X=X\cup Z$$ by applying $\forall Y\;(Y=Y\cup Z)$ to the case $Y=X,$ and we can obtain  $$Z=X\cup Z$$ by applying $\forall Y\;(Y=X\cup Y)$ to the case $Y=Z.$ .... Thus $X=X\cup Z=Z.$

Answer (score 0):

If there is such a set  X then:

$X \cup \emptyset =\emptyset  $

But $X \cup \emptyset = X $

So if such a set exists, it must be the empty set.

The empty set *is* such a set, so such a set does exist and it is uniquely the empty set.

===

2nd argument.

Let S be any set that *isn't* the empty set.  Let $x \in S $.  Let $Y $ be any set that does *not* contain the $x $.

Then $x \in S \cup Y $ so $S \cup Y \ne Y$.

So S doesn't have the property.  So only the empty set has the property.

===

Argument 3:

Let X be such a step.  Then $X^c \cup X = X^c $.  So $X^c $ contains no elements of $X $.  But $X^c \cup X $ contains *all* elements of X.

So if such a set exist it has no elements.  It must be the empty set.